# Dos batch script: using script manipulation deletes the variable entirely

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox

I'm using batch file on DosBox (0.74-3), and i have a variable holding a filename.
when i try to remove/replace the file extention using `%file_name:~0,-3%` or `%file_name:.in=%` (or even `%file_name:%` for that matter) it deletes the variable intirely - trying to echo it prints "ECHO is off".

Ive looked around and couldnt find a way to extract the pure filename via dos batch, or anyone else having this problem. either the suggested way didnt work on dos (`~%n1`) or it's not for my application.

fixes that might help me:

1. fixes for the string manipulation
2. a way to extract the pure filename from string containing path & extention (i figured out removign the path but the extention is killing me)

my code:

```
dir /B %file_name%>temp.temp                    <- extracting the file name (still with extention)
set /p pure_name=<temp.temp
del temp.change_ext
set pure_name=%file_name:~0,-3%                 <- here pure_name will be empty
copy %file_name% %out_dir%\%pure_name%.out >NUL
```

thanks

Comment: you tagged [tag:dosbox] but I doubt that you're actually using DOSBOX. It's **not** the command prompt but a DOS emulator. Your code above won't run in DOS at all, [DOS and cmd are completely different](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Answer (score 0):

edit: i am using DosBox for 8086, so the batch script probably works differently/has less opotions.

found a fix taht did what i want. i am copying the file with new extention to a new folder, so might not be for all uses:

```
rem getting the name of the file without path
if %errorlevel%==0 set /E pure_name = dir /B %file_name%

rem copying the file, while changing the extention
if %errorlevel%==0 copy %file_name% %out_dir%\*.out >NUL
```

Comment: `set` doesn't have a `/E` flag, you can't have spaces around `=` when setting a variable, and you need a `for /f` loop to set the output of a command to a variable.

Comment: are you sure you're running in DOS? Because there's no `set /P` or `set /E` or variable substitutions like `%file_name:~0,-3%` in DOS at all

Comment: `COMMAND.COM` as used by `DOS` (Disk Operating System) does not support most of the syntax as supported by the __Windows__ *Command Processor* `cmd.exe`. I don't know which command line interpreter is used by *DOSBox*. You should find that out first by reading the *DOSBox* documentation. `if %errorlevel%==0` should not be used at all. The correct syntax for exit code evaluation is since MS-DOS `if not errorlevel 1` as explained by the usage help output on running `if /?` even on currently latest Windows 11 (and also by MS-DOS). Spaces around `=` on using `set` has been wrong the last 30 years.